# explanation of probability density function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How can we explain that if a random variable $X$ has pdf $f(x)$ then the function $Y=g(X)$ will have different pdf than $f(x)$ ??
And how to find the pdf of $Y=g(X)$ ??

Comment: Well what do you mean by "explain"? And to find the PDF one typically would setup what follows: let $G$ be the cdf of Y then, $G(a)=Pr(Y\ge a)=Pr(g(X)\ge a)$ we would then solve for X and integrate to get the pdf.

Comment: I need a specific reason so that i can say 'yes it will be different'

Comment: I need the way by which i can calculate the pdf of some function of X if pdf of X is known.

Comment: I can't edit it but the process above should say differentiate, not integrate, and the process exactly explains what you ask.

Comment: sir, please post the solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f$ and CDF $F$. Let $Y=h(X)$ be a new random variable which is a function of $X$ and call its PDF and CDF $f$ and $F$ respectively. Then given some number $y$,

$Pr(Y\le y)=Pr(h(X)\le y)=Pr(X\le h^{-1}(y))=F(h^{-1}(y))$

Taking a derivative of $F(h^{-1}(y))$ with respect to $y$ gives us our answer.